# How to test flutter fingerprint code in emulator?

Tags: flutter

I have a fingerprint code and all, but how can I test this code in emulator? Where do I have to put my thumb? I just don't know how to test this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the emulator provided by the Android SDK, then click on the options menu 3 dots: [image: Emulator Screenshot]

In the setting window select fingerprint.
There you can find the "touch the sensor" button.
 You have to enable fingerprint in the Android settings the same way as you would enable it on a real device.